# Error while trying to get data from httprequest

Tags: c#, json, httprequest

I'm trying to build an application that gets data from a webservice and allows me to process it in my application.

The data I need is being published on a website so in order to get access to the data I had to use the Developer Tools to try and find the call that returns the data on the website.

I have found the call and I can see the requests which are being made so as a first step I'm trying to mimic this call so I get the same results before I do anything else.

However, when I request the data, I'm getting an error stating:

> key must be a string at line 1 column 2

So I'm asssuming there's something wrong with the data I'm sending in the body of my request but I don't know what.

Since the error states that the "Key" must be a string, I thought that I might had to use a Key/Value pair but I can clearly see in the Developer Tools that there is a content type mentioned:

> content-type: application/json

so it seems to me that I need to send JSON.
Also when I look at the Request Payload I am seeing a JSON-formatted string being sent:

```
{"query":"\n      query getData {\n        other data which I have removed for clarity \n        }\n    "}
```

So even when I copy the entire string that I see in the Developer Tools and send that as a JSON-formatted string to the service. I still get the errormessage.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.thesite.com");

            string json = "{'query':'\n      query getData {\n        yada yada yada ...      }\n    '}";
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            
            var result = await client.PostAsync("/data/history", content);
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

I know it's difficult to troubleshoot it like that without having access to the actual data itself. But I'm not looking for someone to fix the problem for me, I'm just trying to understand what the problem actually is.

Am I using the wrong functions? Do I need to actually encode it in JSON again and then serialize it into a json instead of using the actual serialized JSON-string?

Those are the things I'm wondering right now.

I hope someone can enlighten me.

Thanks

Comment: When I post your JSON to a validator, [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/?code=), the version with the single-quotes gives similar error to yours, when I post double-quoted version it returns as valid JSON. Try using escaped double-quotes in your `string json = ...` assignment. e.g. `string json = "{\"query\":\"\n    query getData {\n    yada yada yada  ...   }\n    \"}";`

Comment: You were correct. The single quotes were causing an issue indeed. And the \n newline characters were also giving issues, but after removing those, I got the data back perfectly. Thank you!